# Does an engine with lower viscosity oil require less warming up?

Tags: oil, maintenance, engine-theory, lubrication, warmup

I have always seen that an engine should be driven gently (low throttle, low revs) for about 15 minutes after starting, in order to bring the oil up to temperature and lubricate the engine properly.

If an engine is filled with an oil which has lower viscosity at low temperatures, for example 0w40 compared to 20w40, does the engine require less warming up before it can be driven "properly"?

Comment: The main reason for these new low viscosity oils is fuel efficiency, the side effect is engineers have changed the oiling systems on new cars in various ways that do not tolerate high viscosity oils, but could assume you are correct about reducing warm up time before oil flows to all internal parts in the engine.

Comment: @Moab all the internal parts that need oil / lubrication need it whether or not the engine is warm or has warmed up...

Comment: @SolarMike Duh. Some parts are lubricated by splash, if the oil is too thick due to low temp they will not get needed lubrication.

Comment: @Moab so what do you remember of tribology and a forced lubrication system is designed for a reason either dry sump or not...

Comment: Been working on cars for 45 years, yes I know all about lube systems.